# Font face with Google Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, font-face

Since some days, my Google Chrome browser doesn't show special fonts : CSS with font-face.

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Babel Sans';
    src: url('../fonts/babelsans.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/babelsans.eot?#iefix') format('eot'),
         url('../fonts/babelsans.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../fonts/babelsans.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

All working fine with Safari, Firefox and IE, and it worked fine the last week.
Someone has the same problem and someone know how I can resolve it ?

Thanks,

Comment: Could you let us see how are you actually implement in in you code...

Comment: @EliranMalka, He said it works fine in other browsers.

Comment: @NadavS. thanks for the clarification! I deleted my answer sorry for the overlook!

Comment: @Trufa great.   tilix- Can you show us your whole HTML page? I tested it in my browser with **Babel Sans** and it worked fine. I guess you know that Google Chrome was updated last week? I think the solution can be found there, but the whole page is needed for that.

Comment: Example with the website Galleria : [Galleria Website](http://galleria.io/) - The header is completely crashed. Only with Chrome Mac... [Screenshot](http://img42.imageshack.us/img42/7818/capturedcran20120705171.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's working now, I think Google has update the browser.

Answer (score 1):

I'm experiencing the same issue since Chrome 20 update. This thing happen in Windows Xp and Mac Os X 10.6.8.
Safari and Mobile Safari (that share WebKit engine with Chrome) works perfectly like Firefox and IE.
My css code is exactly like yours.
Looking in the inspector it seems that the font doesn't get downloaded.
Sometimes while navigating different pages (that share the same css external file) in my website the font loads and get displayed properly.

Still trying to solve this...

EDIT:

I managed to solve this issue.
I don't know why, but using this worked:
http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator/

I uploaded my font, got the css and converted files, uploaded them to my server and replaced font-face declaration...bling! It works! Hope that works for you too!

Answer (score 0):

Since there was an update of Chrome for about a week, you may try using an older version to find out if it's a bug (I myself didn't notice any problems). Get one at http://www.oldapps.com/google_chrome.php.
Also check if you're using this font in addion to other font-related CSS values (if so, deactivate them). There were some problems in the past which actually have been solved, but you never know...

Answer (score 0):

**First:** Convert you font using this [service](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator/)  as Mr [Stefano](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1343683/stefano) suggest:

Later use this CSS code to use your font in your project:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'aljazeeraregular';
    src: url('aljazeera-webfont.eot');
    src: url('aljazeera-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('eot'),
         url('aljazeera-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('aljazeera-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('aljazeera-webfont.svg') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}

body {
    background-color: #eaeaea;
    font-family: 'Aljazeera';
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

Note that when you call `font-family` in your site you have to use its original name not like what you declare it in `@font-face`.

Comment: This is not related to the question.